# difference between two variables

Tags: javascript

Hi I was trying to print an array variables on my console of my browser. Firstly I tried to print the below

```
var name = [ 'john', 'mark'];
var years = new Array(1990,1969,1948);

console.log(name[1]);
console.log(name.length);
```

and got the output as below

[image]

And finally I added the `names` instead of `name`
as shown in below code

```
var names = [ 'john', 'mark'];
var years = new Array(1990,1969,1948);

console.log(names[1]);
console.log(names.length);
```

and output for the above code is shown in this

[image]

Can I know whats the difference between?

Comment: there is nothing in code you provided that would suggest such a behaviour, can you show us the rest? are you sure there isnt another variable called name somewhere else that overrides this one?

Comment: There's no reason to link images; paste the actual output into your question.

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski `window.name`

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski its just a basic tutorial I am saving this script in a seprate file and calling in the html file  thats it

Comment: @Pointy while uploading the image i am getting enter image description here since I have less than 10 reputations

Comment: @venkatesh, read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55667170/why-the-array-value-in-the-name-variable-converts-to-string/55667423#55667423) to know the reason, proof and solution of your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are colliding with the built in [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) property

> window.name will convert all values to their string representations by using the toString method.

Answer (score 1):

window.name will provide the name of you current window. More info: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/javascript-the-definitive/0596000480/re335.html

The variable `name` in your example is treated like it was a String, even after you tried to change it to an array.

Print the variables `name` and `names` and you will see the differences.

Output of console.log(name): `"john,mark"`
Output of console.log(names): `["john", "mark"]`

Edit: Reason was provided by @charlietfl

Answer (score 1):

**Reason:**

### `window.name`

> Actually when you defines a variable with **`var`** *keyword* and **`name`** *name*, you are using the **`window.name`** field of the browser DOM.

And when you defines the `name` with `var` keyword it can not override the `string` type and behavior of the `window.name` to `array` and your value will be saved in its as string » `"john,mark"`

**Proof:**

```js
console.log(window.name);

{
  var name = [ 'john', 'mark'];
  
  console.log(window.name);
  console.log(name);
  console.log(name[1]);
  console.log(name.length);
  
}
```

**Solution:**

### `let`

If you want to have a `name` variable other than window.name you should use `let` keyword instead of `var`:

```js
{
  let name = [ 'john', 'mark'];

  console.log(name);
  console.log(name[1]);
  console.log(name.length);
  
}
```